# Error al intentar ingresar objetos en las distintas posiciones de un arreglo JavaScript Cannot read property 'registros' of undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6

Hola colegas tengo una gran pregunta, espero puedan ayudarme

tengo estos datos

```
    const datos = 
      { cod_leccionario: 25496,
        iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
        curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
        paralelo: 'A        ',
        fecha: '07/08/2018',
        hora: 8,
        materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
        destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
        tareas: '',
        observaciones: '',
        profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
        firma: 'No esta firmado',
        observaciones_coordinador: '',
        observaciones_inspector: '' },
      { cod_leccionario: 25498,
        iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
        curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
        paralelo: 'A        ',
        fecha: '07/08/2018',
        hora: 9,
        materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
        destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
        tareas: '',
        observaciones: '',
        profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
        firma: 'No esta firmado',
        observaciones_coordinador: '',
        observaciones_inspector: '' },
      { cod_leccionario: 25502,
        iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
        curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
        paralelo: 'A        ',
        fecha: '08/08/2018',
        hora: 1,
        materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
        destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
        tareas: '',
        observaciones: '',
        profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
        firma: 'No esta firmado',
        observaciones_coordinador: '',
        observaciones_inspector: '' },
      { cod_leccionario: 25507,
        iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
        curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
        paralelo: 'A        ',
        fecha: '08/08/2018',
        hora: 2,
        materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
        destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
        tareas: '',
        observaciones: '',
        profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
        firma: 'No esta firmado',
        observaciones_coordinador: '',
        observaciones_inspector: '' },
      { cod_leccionario: 25901,
        iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
        curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
        paralelo: 'A        ',
        fecha: '14/08/2018',
        hora: 7,
        materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
        destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
        tareas: '',
        observaciones: '',
        profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
        firma: 'No esta firmado',
        observaciones_coordinador: '',
        observaciones_inspector: '' },
      { cod_leccionario: 25904,
        iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
        curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
        paralelo: 'A        ',
        fecha: '14/08/2018',
        hora: 8,
        materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
        destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
        tareas: '',
        observaciones: '',
        profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
        firma: 'No esta firmado',
        observaciones_coordinador: '',
        observaciones_inspector: '' }
```

Tengo un arreglo al que intento ingresarles estos objetos en las distintas posiciones del arreglo agrupados por la fecha, los que tienes fecha `'07/08/2018'` que vayan en la posición 0, lo que tienen fecha `'08/08/2018'` que vayan en la posición 1 y así consecutivamente, para ello cree estas lineas de codigo:

```
let data = [];
data.push({registros:[]});
let k = 0;
let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    if (datos[i].fecha == datos[j].fecha) {
      data[k].registros.push(datos[i]);
      j = i;
    } else {
      k++;
      data[k].registros.push(datos[i]);
      j = i;
    }
  }
console.log(data);
```

pero al ejecularlo tengo el siguiente error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'registros' of undefined
```

probe cambiando `data[k]` quemandole la posición `data[0]` (para realizar pruebas) y ahí si ingresa los datos, solo que todos van en la misma posición y no es lo que deseo, tambien intente poner `data[data.length-1]` en el `if` y `data[data.length]` en el `else`, pero obtengo el mismo error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'registros' of undefined`

Comment: El error se debe a que solo estas añadiendo `registros`a la primera posición, en las demás no existe y por eso te dice que no esta definido.

Comment: @ElGerar como lograría generar una nueva posición para poder ingresar los demas datos?

Comment: estas definiendo mal tu arreglo de la variable datos!! , es solo un objeto y mal definido debe ser  algo como `const datos = [{obj1 : 1},{obj1 : 2}....]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo creas un elemento inicial:

```
data.push( { registros:[] } );
```

Con lo que cualquier acceso a un elemento de índice `!= 0` te resultará en el error que comentas.

Para solucionarlo, no tienes mas que crear el elemento para el índice en cuestión **antes** de intentar modificar sus atributos:

```
if( datos[i].fecha == datos[j].fecha ) {
  data[k].registros.push( datos[i] );
  j = i;
} else {
  k++;
  data[k] = { registros: [] };
  data[k].registros.push( datos[i] );
  j = i;
}
```

Comment: sigo obteniendo el mismo error, en tu condición dices "si k es igual a data.length" pero en k sigue valiendo 0 mientras que data.length vale 1 por ende no se cumple.
Como puedo generar una nueva posición?

Comment: Solo tienes que hacer `push( )`, cómo ya estás haciendo. Ahora le hecho otra mirada.

Comment: @SiulLeinadAvalaSerrot Ya, editado.

Comment: justo lo que necesiba, mil gracias, solo una pequeña observación, el `data[k] = { registros: [] };` que va dentro del `if` no iria, ya que me elimina lo que tengo grabado y guarda el nuevo dato, solo lo he puesto en el `else` como tienes en la respuesta y el resto lo deje igual, me va de maravilla

Comment: ¡ Perfecto ! La edito, para que quede bien :-)